# XYZ Reader app sample not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design

I am newbie in Android and try'n follow up some tutorial on Material design [here](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud862/lessons/6994540280/concepts/69947500210923).

But unfortunately, the sample provided is not working due to [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/231329/xyzreader_data/data.json) dropbox url got expired that is fetching some list of data from server.

Does anyone gone through with this sample recently and found any other source of data to run this material design sample.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They changed this [Dropbox URL](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/231329/xyzreader_data/data.json) to https://go.udacity.com/xyz-reader-json

But new URL provides JSON which has wrong value for `aspact_ratio` fields so I calculated the correct values for these fields and re-hosted the file on [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/electron0zero/07a1cddde7948d72dc2c0a12163f92fa)

Answer (score 0):

I found one more useful project to learn the concepts of Material design. You can check it [here](https://github.com/Eajy/MaterialDesignDemo). It may help you too.

Thanks.